# When I enter A, B, C, or D, it still says That is not a valid answer. Why?

Tags: java, string

This is my project for school. We were asked to make a little quiz and I want to make sure when the user enters something outside of the options, they will get an error message saying that is not a valid answer, but whatever I enter it still says that is not valid. Why?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  String answer;
  int score = 0;
  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("ALL SUBJECT QUIZ Starting now, please enter the correct option (Letters or T or F) for the next 10 questions");
      System.out.println("Question 1 (Maths): What is the vertex of the equation y=2(x-2)^2+5");
      System.out.println("A. (-2,5)" + "\n" + "B. (2, 5)" + "\n" + "C. (-2,-5)" + "\n" + "D. (2, -5)");
      answer = input.nextLine();
      answer = answer.toUpperCase();
      
      while (!answer.equals("A") || !answer.equals("B") || !answer.equals("C") || !answer.equals("D")) {
        System.out.println("That is not a valid response");
        answer = input.nextLine();
        answer = answer.toUpperCase();
      }
        if (answer.equals("A")) {
          System.out.println("Incorrect, the answer is B");
        } else if (answer.equals("B")){
          System.out.println("Correct");
          score += 1;
        } else if (answer.equals("C")){
          System.out.println("Incorrect, the answer is B");
        } else if (answer.equals("D")){
          System.out.println("Incorrect, the answer is B");
        }

  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: `while (!answer.equals("A") || !answer.equals("B") || !answer.equals("C") || !answer.equals("D"))` - bad logic, it's always going to be not equal to at least 3 out of these 4 options (hence always true).

Comment: Change each one of those `||` to `&&`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's evaluate your following condition:

```
!answer.equals("A") || !answer.equals("B") || !answer.equals("C") || !answer.equals("D")
```

Assume, **answer = E**

Now, your condition will be evaluated as

`true || !answer.equals("B") || !answer.equals("C") || !answer.equals("D")` => `true`

Note that when multiple conditions are joined with `||`, the evaluation stops as soon as a `true` condition is found.

Assume, **answer = B**

Now, your condition will be evaluated as

`true || !answer.equals("B") || !answer.equals("C") || !answer.equals("D")` => `true`

Assume, **answer = A**

Now, your condition will be evaluated as

`false || true || !answer.equals("C") || !answer.equals("D")` => `true`

Thus, you see that irrespective of the answer, the condition always evaluates to `true`.

### Solution:

Change it to

```
while (!(answer.equals("A") || answer.equals("B") || answer.equals("C") || answer.equals("D")))
```

which means the answer is not (`A`, or `B`, or `C`, or `D`)

Alternatively, you can change it to

```
while (!answer.equals("A") && !answer.equals("B") && !answer.equals("C") && !answer.equals("D"))
```

which means the answer is not `A` and the answer is not `B` and the answer is not `C` and the answer is not `D`.

However, for the sake of simplicity, my taste is the first one.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at your while loop condition, you will notice that it will always evaluate to `true` because the user input can't equal `A`, `B`, `C`, and `D` all at once.

So the solution here is to change the or's (`||`) in the condition to and's (`&&`) since you want the user input to be only one of the following: `A`, `B`, `C`, or `D`.

```
while (!answer.equals("A") && !answer.equals("B") && !answer.equals("C") && !answer.equals("D")) {
    System.out.println("That is not a valid response");
    answer = input.nextLine();
    answer = answer.toUpperCase();
}
```